# What does the -a flag mean when using git pull -a origin develop?

Tags: git, pull

Normally when I want to update my project from a remote repository I use the following command line.

```
git pull -a origin develop
```

I learned this from my project team members but I could not find the answer on the Internet what the -a flag does. What does the -a mean?

Comment: Quick Google search: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull--a **Append ref names and object names of fetched refs to the existing contents of .git/FETCH_HEAD. Without this option old data in .git/FETCH_HEAD will be overwritten.**

Answer (score 7):

The `git pull` command is essentially just a convenience shortcut.<sup>1</sup>  It first runs `git fetch`, then it runs another Git command.  The second Git command defaults to `git merge`, but under various circumstances, you can make the second command be `git rebase`.

*This is **all** that `git pull` does: It runs two other Git commands.  All options and arguments to `git pull` either control which second command it uses, or are passed on, usually directly, to one of the other commands.*

In this case, `-a` or `--append` is passed on to `git fetch`, which tells it to append all of the fetched references to the `FETCH_HEAD` file (rather than replacing any existing `FETCH_HEAD` file iwth fetched references).  Unless you are using `FETCH_HEAD` yourself, this option is useless.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since the best *second* command to run can depend on the result of the *first* command, as conveniences go, this one is really very inconvenient.  It's like having to decide whether to walk, drive, or fly to a destination before you know whether it's in your neighborhood, in your city, or in another continent.

Answer (score 0):

... pull -a is the same as --append.
From the official documentation:

> -a
>
> --append Append ref names and object names of fetched refs to the existing contents of .git / FETCH_HEAD. Without this option old data
>
> in .git / FETCH_HEAD will be overwritten.

If you just want to update the history of your branch try to use

> > git fetch
>
> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.
>   In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by
>   git merge FETCH_HEAD.
>
> More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and
>   calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current
>   branch. With --rebase, it runs git rebase instead of git merge.

Documentation:

> [fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)
>
> [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Answer (score -1):

From `git pull --help`:

> -a, --append Append ref names and object names of fetched refs to the existing contents of .git/FETCH_HEAD. Without this option old data in .git/FETCH_HEAD will be overwritten.